# Why can I not use sibling and :first-child on a list of heterogenous elements?

Tags: css, siblings, css-selectors

I'm stuck trying to access an element via CSS and don't understand why.

I have a random number of `<label><div>` combinations like this:

```
<div class="sample">
   <label></label>
   <div class="ui-random-foo"></div>
   <label></label>
   <div class="ui-random-bar"></div>
   <label></label>
   <div class="ui-random-baz"></div>
</div>
```

I don't know how many element pairs I will get and wanted to set the width depending on the number of elements. However while my selector:

```
.sample label ~ div
```

works and returns all three `<div>` in the above example, doing:

```
.sample label ~ div:first-child
```

does not work.

**Question**
Why can I not use first-child? I had hoped my sibling selector would return a group of `div` elements, so I'm using first-child on homogenous elements? Or is there another problem?

Comment: [first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) selects only the first child element in the parent

Comment: `:first-child` targets the first child of the container, and not the first child div

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to your issue? Please accept the answer you found most helpfull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found another solution which fits my need best:

```
.sample :first-child:nth-last-child(2) ~ div {
   width: 60%;
}
.sample  :first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ div {
   width: 30%;
}
.sample :first-child:nth-last-child(6) ~ div {
   width: 20%;
}
.sample :first-child:nth-last-child(8) ~ div  {
  width: 15%;
}
```

So I'm not filtering for anything, because I know there will always be pairs of elements, so I'm checking for 2,4,6,8 elements and set the width of sibling divs respectively. Seems to work. Thanks @Huangism for the idea.

Answer (score 4):

The first child is a label element. The first div is the second child.

You could use:

```
.sample label:first-child + div
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use :

```
.sample div:first-of-type
```

to select the first div.

EXAMPLE :

```css
.sample *{
    height:10px;
    display:block;
    margin-top:5px;
    background:teal;
}
.sample div:first-of-type{
    background:gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="sample">
   <label></label>
   <div class="ui-random-foo"></div>
   <label></label>
   <div class="ui-random-bar"></div>
   <label></label>
   <div class="ui-random-baz"></div>
</div>
```